# Including css on each php page inc subfolder

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating my first (basic) php application and would like to start as I mean to go on as regards file paths and globals - this is quite new to me. WHat I have now works however I would like to be advised if there is a more efficient way (for future-proofing/expansion)

I have a simple file structure as follows;

```
- css
 -- bootstrap.css
- lib
 -- display.php
- template
 -- header.php
 -- footer.php
- admin
 -- login.php
- globals.php
- index.php
```

I would like to include my css (`bootstrap.css`) on each page. I have declared a single global in my `global.php` as follows;

```
<?php define('URL', 'http://localhost/myLocalSite'); ?>
```

The in my `display.php` I have included the css;

```
<link href="<?php echo URL ?>css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo URL ?>css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I include these in my `index.php` by using the following;

```
<?php include('globals.php') ?>
<?php include('template/header.php') ?>
<?php include('lib/display.php') ?>
```

I include these in my `login.php` by using the following (not the sub-folder location);

```
<?php include('../globals.php') ?>
<?php include('../template/header.php') ?>
<?php include('../lib/display.php') ?>
```

Whenever working in a file within a sub-directory (as above `login.php`) do I always need to include the `../` in order to include the files or is there a better way?

Like I say it works and I am new to this so ay advice is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the composer dependency framework for php https://getcomposer.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead if you want to remove PHP Processing logic, i would suggest using HTML `<base>` tag in your HTML `<head>` section, You can see example usage [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

```
<base href="http://www.yoursite.com/" target="_blank">
```

Then you have to change these below lines

```
<link href="<?php echo URL ?>css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo URL ?>css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This will eliminate PHP processing part

Comment: The main benefit is, in all pages you will not have to deal with include urls, consider `css/styles.css` which will be same in all your pages, `<base>` prepends to all the urls in your pages

Comment: Thanks this works. However I still have to add `<?php include('../lib/display.php') ?>` to my `login.php` page in order for the css to render.

Comment: yes, thats the point, where you need css, include `display.php`, this is only for eliminating php part `<?php echo URL ?>`

Comment: Perfect. I'll accept this answer as it's simple and it works. Thanks @Viral

Answer (score 4):

You can make index.php your Router and then rewrite request to it.
Then you can declare a constant in index file and load other files from it.

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

and then you can include files everywhere like this

```
require(ROOT.'/globals.php');
require(ROOT.'/template/header.php');
require(ROOT.'/lib/display.php');
```

For ONLY example router:
`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Then you can do anything in index.php, for example:

```
   <?php
    $uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    require "templates/header.php";
    switch ($uri) {
        case "/":
            include "views/index.php";
            break;
        case "/login":
            include "admin/login.php";
            break;
        case "/something":
            include "views/something.php";
            break;
        default:
            include "views/404.php";
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            break;
    }
    require "template/footer.php";
```

Future improvements:

- You can automate it in some way, to not create next case for each
  file
- [Some tutorial on php routing](http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/), but watch out for security reasons - dont include SECRET files

Comment: What does it mean, it dont work? Errors or stragne behavior? You dont need to have `<?php include('../globals.php') ?>
<?php include('../template/header.php') ?>` in login.php Just in index.php

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer +1. I have to however accept the answer by @Viral as it makes more sense to me at this point (newbie). I will however read more about routing!